# Slow performance with angular material md-select and ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-material

I'm writing an enterprise application using angular and angular material and have problem with the performance of a medium sized (in my opinion) form. Especially in IE.

(Working demo, see https://codepen.io/tkarls/pen/vGrqWv . Klick on the card title and it pauses slightly before opens. Especially using IE and mobile. Desktop chrome works pretty well.)

The worst offenders in the form seem to be some md-selects with ng-repeat on them.

```
<md-select ng-model="form.subchannelId" ng-disabled="vm.readOnly">
    <md-option ng-repeat="id in subchannelIds" value="{{::id}}">{{::id}}</md-option>
</md-select>
<md-select ng-model="form.serviceReference" ng-disabled="vm.readOnly">
    <md-option ng-repeat="id in serviceReferences" value="{{::id}}">{{::countryId}}{{::id}}</md-option>
</md-select>
<md-select ng-model="form.audioCodec" ng-disabled="vm.readOnly">
    <md-option ng-repeat="audioCodec in audioCodecs | orderBy:'toString()'" value="{{audioCodec}}">{{::systemVariables.encoders.aac[audioCodec].displayName}}</md-option>
</md-select>
<md-select ng-model="form.audioSource" ng-disabled="vm.readOnly">
    <md-option ng-repeat="audioSource in audioSources | orderBy:'toString()'" value="{{audioSource}}">{{audioSource}}</md-option>
</md-select>
<md-select ng-model="form.padSource" ng-disabled="vm.readOnly">
    <md-option ng-repeat="padSource in padSources | orderBy:'toString()'" value="{{::padSource}}">{{::padSource}}</md-option>
</md-select>
<md-select ng-model="form.lang" ng-disabled="!form.generateStaticPty || vm.readOnly">
    <md-option ng-repeat="langKey in langKeys | orderBy:'toString()'" value="{{::langs[langKey]}}">{{::langKey}}</md-option>
</md-select>
<md-select ng-model="form.pty" ng-disabled="!form.generateStaticPty || vm.readOnly">
    <md-option ng-repeat="ptyKey in ptyKeys | orderBy:'toString()'" value="{{::ptys[ptyKey]}}">{{::ptyKey}}</md-option>
</md-select>
```

The data model looks like:

```
$scope.subchannelIds = [0, 1, 2]; //up to 63 in real life
$scope.serviceReferences = ["000", "001", "002"]; //up to 999 in real life
$scope.ptys = {
  "No programme type": 0,
  "News": 1,
  "Current Affairs": 2}; //Up to ~30 in real life
$scope.ptyKeys = Object.keys($scope.ptys);
$scope.langs = {
  "Unknown": "00",
  "Albanian": "01",
  "Breton": "02"}; //Up to ~100 in real life
$scope.langKeys = Object.keys($scope.langs);
```

The other ng-repeats are small with 3-5 items each. I think that a modern browser should handle datasets of this size and render it very quickly. So hopefully I'm doing something wildly wrong with my HTML code. The data is fetched from the server in real life but I do pre-fetch it so once the form is ready to be displayed it is already in the $scope.

I tried to pre-generate HTML after I fetched the data using normal js loops. And then insert just the html snippet like:
    
        {{::preGeneratedHtmlHere}}

But then angular would not treat it as html but text...

Any help on how to optimize this is appreciated!

Comment: if u can use pregenerated html, try binding html like ng-bind-html="<pregenarated-html>". Make sure you have ng-sanitize as well

Comment: @Murwa I've tried binding the html with ng-bind-html but it doesn't work. The HTML contains custom directives (well, angular material directives) that need to be compiled by angular to display. So, any idea how to get the compiled HTML into the dom?

Comment: that'll be tricky, coz u need to $compile it

Comment: I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17417607/angular-ng-bind-html-unsafe-and-directive-within-it and it works. I will change all repeats and then see what it did for the performance

Comment: Just letting you know. It did work doing the compile myself. But it didn't improve the performance. I guess it was still the same number of nodes that needed to be inserted into the dom.

Comment: I guess huge DOM generated by loading dropdown with 1000 items($scope.serviceReferences) could be real culprit and not angularJS/material. Try without angular and see how its behaving?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Angular material has very poor performance, because the objects pinned to the scope are huge, which makes the digest cycle very long and inperformant.

You should try it first with the default `select` and `ng-options` ([DOCS HERE](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)). If this works better for you, I'd suggest using plain html and then use [MaterializeCSS](http://materializecss.com/) to get the look and feel of Material Design.

Comment: I see, I'll try and convert it to plain html selects and see what happens with the performance

Comment: I tested it now without any css styling. And in chrome the form is now blazingly fast. And IE is improved but still not good enough.

Comment: I'm selecting this as the accepted answer since doing it greatly improved the performance. However, to get the final user experience good enough I also combined ng-if and ng-show. So that ng-if = true on moseover and then ng-show = true on click. That created very rapid forms in both explorer and chrome!

Comment: I've explained my technique here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36795321/1226268 for anyone finding this on google.

Comment: Actually the objects are not necessary huge, it depends on what you define. Also the digest cycle is all about updates, while the original question complains about initial (compile + link) performance. As I wrote in my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36764414/slow-performance-with-angular-material-md-select-and-ng-repeat/37652007#37652007 this is because md-select, compiles all options. This can be deferred until the dropdown has been clicked. Fine-tune it by getting the list on focus maybe.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, making it all plain old html will speed it up, however then you lose all the eye candy. To have the good parts from both of the worlds you can do some basic optimizations.

1. Do you really need to watch the collection - are the collections
   going to change and if so can't you trigger a digest then? As you did
   with the id you can also one-way bind the repeated collection as
   well.

   `ng-repeat="id in ::serviceReferences"`

---

2. You don't really need
   all the options preloaded, right? Since you're using
   angular-material, the default drop-down will be exchanged with
   multiple elements, to emulate the drop-down behavior. I did just
   remove the options list, replaced it with the actually selected
   element and populate the list only when the control has gained
   focus. See [documentation](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdSelect).

Still I agree the angular-material has a poor performance. It simply does not scale well. 1-2 controls work but if you have more then 10 it starts to fail.

PS.: Don't cook the $scope soup!

Comment: This made just enough difference that the timing is acceptable for me. I didn't have a large number of items and actually thought the animation timing might just have been too slow, but this JUST brought the performance to an acceptable point and works since my lists won't be updating.

Answer (score 2):

For a big amount of items in `ng-repeat` will cause some issues. When angular use `ng-repeat` to create nested list , a single watcher will be created for each item. Hundreds of watchers will slow down the performance obviously on moible (and IE probably). We used have this issue with `ng-repeat`, so the best practice is avoid using `ng-repeat` if you could, create and attach the `watcher` when you really need to.

So I think the possible solution is, try to use normal for loop instead of `ng-repeat`.

Comment: Right, I did try to reduce the number of watcher by using the {{::id}} syntax. But it does not seem to matter for the inital load time. If doing normal loop. How do I attach the html. ng-bind-html as @Murwa suggests?

Comment: Yeah, I saw you use `::id` which is one-way binding. If you want to get rid of the watchers you need to write the directive yourself and that means a lots of coding.